# Сделать приложение браузером по-умолчанию

Tags: c#, windows, браузер

Как можно программно (либо прям на c#, либо каким-либо установщиком [например InnoSetup]) сделать свою программу браузером по-умолчанию в Windows 7+?

Comment: В последних версиях Windows появилось "Приложения по-умолчанию". Хотелось бы запустить это окно. Как это делают Chrome, Mozilla, Yandex?

Comment: Есть ответ на SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25243587/5275890

Answer (score 5):

Ветка реестра HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command отвечает за приложение для открытия ссылок с http-протоколом. Аналогичная есть для https.

Comment: Если я так сделаю, то ничего не заработает. В последних версиях Windows появилось "Приложения по-умолчанию". Хотелось бы запустить это окно.

Comment: @mcfev А вы пробовали вообще?

Comment: Да, и не раз, на WinXP даже получилось. Тут вопрос в другом, мне надо вообще всё что ссылается на браузер (http,https,htm файлы,html файлы и пр.). А для этого должно быть что-то еще, чем просто переписать ветки реестра.

Comment: @mcfev Вы не поверите, но реестр - конечный пункт, и именно он отвечает за то, что где и в чем открывается.

Comment: Ладно, что заставляет открыть окно "Приложения по-умолчанию" и какая ветка отвечает за попадание приложения в это окно?

Comment: @mcfev [документация MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) по добавлению вашего приложения в список приложений по умолчанию. Однако в конечном счете, если вы хотите сделать свое приложение браузером по умолчанию, вам придется изменить ассоциации для всех 14 протоколов/расширений. Другого пути просто нет.